# Scaling and Translation of $\delta$-distribution

Tags: dirac-delta

The following properties of the $\delta$-distribution are known:

$\delta(ax) = \frac{1}{|a|}\delta(x)$ and $\delta(x-a)$ is a translation

what happens now if I have something of the form $\delta(B-ax)$? Can I still pull out the $a$ in a way?

Thanks in advance!